# SignalR 1.1.3 gets thousands of 404 responses trying to reconnect during IE Longpolling

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I'm having an issue with SignalR that is causing IE (9) to send thousands of ping/reconnect attempts to the server within a second or two.

`signalr/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=(some long token here)...`

It gets a 404 (along with the full 404 response)

and then does another ping:
`signalr/ping?_=(ID)`

Which gets a "pong" response and then attempts another reconnect as above.

The issue is it tries this and fails a few thousand times (last test was 6,800+ ping/reconnects). Not only is this a lot of bad server talk, but it also chews through bandwidth pretty fast sending and receiving all these responses.

It finally ends up sending a `signalr/negotiate` which succeeds and stops the ping/reconnect madness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the 2.0.0 release via https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2125.

Comment: Ok thanks, not the answer I was hoping to but guess that means its time to migrate to the RC. Thanks! :)